# how to use if statement to do a conditional check inside specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, specs

I have this config/initializer.rb which lets me load a yaml /config/application.yaml and do something like APP_CONFIG["myvar"] how could I enable this for my SPECS also?

My goal is to do something like:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe BetaController do
  describe "routing" do

    if APP_CONFIG["viral"] and APP_CONFIG["beta"]

      it "routes to #index do" do
        get("/").should route_to("home#index")
      end

    end

  end
end
```

Comment: Is this a gem you're using, or something you wrote yourself?

Comment: @farleyknight something like this :http://fredwu.me/post/632640092/rails-use-app-config-for-your-application-specific

Comment: That blog post is from 2010, and the project it links to is no longer maintained. I'd look for a way to migrate to the new project that is linked to on the github page.

Comment: From the [Github page](https://github.com/cjbottaro/app_config): This project is no longer supported or maintained. It has been superceded by ConfigSpartan: github.com/cjbottaro/config_spartan

Comment: @farleyknight just google for app_config ruby on rails and pick a more recent blog post its documented several times good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using this gem:

https://github.com/oshuma/app_config

```
Given this YAML file:

---
admin_email: 'admin@example.com'
api_name:    'Supr Webz 2.0'
api_key:     'SUPERAWESOMESERVICE'
Use it like so:

AppConfig.setup!(yaml: '/path/to/app_config.yml')

# Later on...
AppConfig.admin_email  # => 'admin@example.com'
AppConfig.api_name     # => 'Supr Webz 2.0'
AppConfig.api_key      # => 'SUPERAWESOMESERVICE'
```

This could easily be added to your `spec_helper`

Comment: actually i have this already implemented, but an if statement fails in the spec itself. I kinda have a global and production, development section that is getting read more advanced than this gem  i rephrase question its to unclear now

Comment: Repost your question if it's completely different from the original.